# What angular version I need to run SurveyJS..?

Tags: angular, version, angular7, surveyjs

Recently I have been facing issues in SurveyJS with angular v7, Earlier it was easily working on angular version 7 but now For few months I am facing error of 503 connection error. I have tried every thing but no outcome.

I have tried researching online but have got no results, If anyone can help me with this, lemme know

Answer (score 0):

500 errors are backend errors, generally 503 meaning service unreachable.
So it's a server problem, but what does SurveyJs have to do with it?

Comment: SurveyJS updated their version and brought licensing and SurveyJS only works for Angular v13 and above now

Comment: Yes but survey-angular-ui, no the js library.  Anyway yours seems to be a server problem,  Did you try to call him by postman?

Answer (score 0):

**[Updated]**

You can use the [survey-angular-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/survey-angular-ui) package to run SurveyJS Form Library in your Angular application. As noted, SurveyJS for Angular requires Angular v12.0.0 or newer.

For more information, refer to the following getting-started tutorial: [Add a Survey to an Angular Application](https://surveyjs.io/form-library/documentation/get-started-angular).

If you're running Angular 12 or older (e.g, Angular 10), use the [survey-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/survey-angular) package. An example is available at https://github.com/surveyjs/code-examples/tree/main/legacy-angular.